# Google Places API: Specify State in URL Params

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm having trouble finding a way to filter Google Places results by city and state. My example below searches Dominos Pizza in "Springfield." The results contain many different states. How could I specify "Springfield, CT"?

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=dominos+pizza+in+springfield&key=123

Answer (score 0):

You can append the location to your request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=dominos&sensor=false&location=40.67,-73.94&radius=100
```

See the full documentation here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

Comment: Yes, I read this in the documentation. But I don't have the lat/lng coords. All I have is the business/landmark, city and state. I can parse the results to pull only results for my target state, but you'd think the option to filter by state would be something that is already built into the API. Similar to calling "dominos+pizza+in+springfield", there should also be the capacity to filter further like "dominos+pizza+in+springfield,+CT". So far, I've not been able to find anything.

Comment: Then you can do a request to the geocode service to find the coords.
here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Comment: That's a fair suggestion, but I don't like the idea of having to call two different web services to accomplish something that should be accomplished in a single call to a single service. Worst case scenario, I'll just parse the data from Google Places. But I don't want to go down that road unless Google hasn't provided a State filter per this service.